# Where can I get drm contents?

Tags: cobalt

I Developing drm in Cobalt(RC_9). I want to develop and debug drm with drm contents.

1. where can I get drm contents?

Comment: You can purchase DRM contents from the YouTube Movies channel. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClgRkhTL3_hImCAmdLfDE4g

Comment: not provide DRM contents for Test? Do I have to buy unconditionally?

Comment: I resloved it. thank u Juyung.

Comment: "Sintel" costs $0. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MeFoUwes8nE. For coupons, please contact your YouTube account manager.

Answer (score 0):

[Summary]
- Purchase movies from "YouTube Movies" channel: https://youtube.com/channel/UClgRkhTL3_hImCAmdLfDE4g
You can also purchase movies from Google Play Movies and watch them on YouTube with the same Google account.
- $0 movie "Sintel" is available: https://youtube.com/watch?v=MeFoUwes8nE
- Contact your YouTube partner manager for free coupons.

Comment: Hi Danial, we can also use http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/demo-player/dash-player-020416.html Thanks, Vlad

Comment: I recommend you to use http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/demo-player/dash-player-2018.html for Cobalt. But I still recommend you to purchase some movies to test with.